# Installer for copy-files-only possible?

Tags: install4j

We need an installer to copy or upload some files to some places without install any files to the os. So we do not need any uninstaller or updater or any stored file to an installation directory. We only want to use install4j to pack some files we want to unpack/copy/upload to some location during "installation". Therefore we also need some user input like storage location (not installation directory because could also be an url) or user credential for a server-upload-interface. The installer should be released as a cd with a structure like:

```
cd-root
 |-- installer.exe
 |-- files
   |-- file1.txt
   |-- file2.txt
   |....
```

Is such an installer possible with install4j? We used install4j for other "normal" installer projects and would be happy to use it for this scenario too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Install files" action has a "Install runtime" property that can be deselected, so no .install4j directory or bundled JRE is installed into the installation directory.

The Uninstaller can be disabled on the "Screens & Actions" step.

After the "Install files action", the files can by transferred to another location with a "Copy files or directories" action.